# When using a pointer to use functions with polymorphism, does the pointer have to be of the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, polymorphism

When I compile and run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void doSomething()
    {
        cout << endl << "hi this is base";
    }

};

class DerivedA : public Base
{
    public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        cout << endl << "hi this is derivedA";
    }
};

class DerivedB : public Base
{
    public:
    void doSomething(){
        cout << endl << "hi this is derivedB";
    }
};

int main () {
    DerivedB bb;
    Base* cc;
    cc = (DerivedA*) &bb;
    cc->doSomething();
}
```

The output is `hi this is derivedB"`.

Now is this just a case where I have done something strictly illegal and my compiler manages to compile it anyway? Because I would imagine a `DerivedA` pointer would not know that it is pointing to a `DerivedB` object when calling `doSomething` as there is no Base class/Derived Class relationship there.

Is there a resource that explains the intricacies behind C++'s inheritance and polymorphism more in-depth than the tutorial at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ ?

Comment: This question is a little similar to yours and contains some discussion on the topic: [C++ virtual function not called in subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105282/c-virtual-function-not-called-in-subclass)

Comment: What compiler do you use? MSVC, generates error,  gcc generates warning (except of a very few cases, c++ compiler warning points to something that really should not appear in correct code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cc = (DerivedA*) &bb;
```

Ding ding ding! Undefined behaviour right here!

> Now is this just a case where I have done something strictly illegal

Yep, totally illegal. Or well, not exactly illegal, but undefined behaviour, which is pretty much illegal.

To answer the question title: No, you don't need a base-class pointer. However, you can't just cast between unrelated types and hope it works.

Comment: Not true. You can cast a pointer to a pointer of a different type. The results may be unspecified but it is not UB. However, because the result is unspecified it may be that the result of then converting that pointer to `Base*` may not actually point at a valid `Base` object. In this case `cc->doSomething()` _will_ cause UB.

Comment: @Charles: You're right. `§5.2.10 p7` explicitly says that this kind of conversion is indeed unspecified only. Brb, looking if derived-to-base pointer conversion on such a result is defined in any way.

Comment: My standard foo is failing me, atleast I can't find any mentioning of how calling a virtual function on a possible wrong base subobject is handled.

Comment: It comes under 3.10/1: "If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined". The glvalue in this case is `*(cc)` because `cc->doSomething()` is equivalent to `(*(cc)).doSomething()`.

Comment: @Charles: Perfect, thanks! I'll whip it together and edit the answer in a minute.

Comment: @Charles: Hm, that part doesn't actually answer the question. :/ "— a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,". It *is* a base-class type, it just might be the wrong subobject. Any idea where to find info about that?

Comment: No, the pointer could point at a completely random location. The result of the cast from `DerivedB*` to `DerivedA*` is completely unspecified; the implementation must be able to recover the original value if cast back but you don't know anything else about the resulting `DerivedA*`.

Answer (score 1):

DeriveA  is Base and DeriveB is Base these two types derived from the base class you can use a Base pointer to call DeriveA Or DeriveB (polymorphysim) but u cannot go from a subtype to another

Answer (score 1):

As Xeo pointed out, your code is compilable but with undefined behavior. You should use explicit casting operators -- `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `const_cast` -- of C++ to prevent such errors.

Check out the section about `dynamic_cast`: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: `(DerivedA*) &bb` is - in this case - guaranteed to be completely equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<DerivedA*>(&bb)`. Simply switching to the appropriate C++ style cast isn't going to fix any undefined behaviour. Using a C++ compile cast only helps catch cases where an unintented style of cast is being used in a C style cast expression.

Comment: In this case, the appropriate C++ style recommends using `dynamic_cast`, which will prevent the undefined behavior. That's why I recommended that section. Maybe I should have been more explicit.

Comment: Just converting to a `dynamic_cast` will result in a null pointer value. `cc->doSomething()` would _still_ cause UB. Using `dynamic_cast` is usually discouraged where a simpler solution exists. Here a simple `cc = &bb;` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Of course `cc = &bb` would be more appropriate as we see that `bb` is an instance of `DerivedB` by looking at the code. But I assumed that the question was about casting polymorphic types into each other in which case you should use `dynamic_cast` operator and check if the result is null.

Comment: Sure, I just hestitate to even recommend `dynamic_cast` unless I'm sure that it's one of the rare use cases where it is actually appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Casting a pointer to a `DerivedB` object to a `DerivedA` object and then calling one of `DerivedA`'s functions the way you're doing it is asking for trouble (and essentially undefined behaviour), since `DerivedB` isn't derived from type `DerivedA`.

It's not strictly "illegal" as far as the compiler's concerned, but you shouldn't be doing that and it's not something you'd want to be doing if you wanted reliable behaviour from your code.

If you want extra checking to be done at runtime you should check out `dynamic_cast`, as opposed to using a C-style cast.

Why it may work has to do with the way the vtable is laid out. With g++, if you compile with the command `-fdump-class-hierarchy` you'll get a dump of the vtable like so:

```
Vtable for DerivedA
DerivedA::_ZTV8DerivedA: 3u entries
0     (int (*)(...))0
8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI8DerivedA)
16    (int (*)(...))DerivedA::doSomething

...

Vtable for DerivedB
DerivedB::_ZTV8DerivedB: 3u entries
0     (int (*)(...))0
8     (int (*)(...))(& _ZTI8DerivedB)
16    (int (*)(...))DerivedB::doSomething
```

As you can see, the function `doSomething` is at the same offset for both instances of types `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`. The pointer in this case is pointing to `DerivedB::doSomething`, which is why the output is `"hi this is derivedB"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cc = (DerivedA*) &bb;
```

Because `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` are not related by a direct inheritance path you can't use a `static_cast` to convert from `DerivedB*` to `DerivedA*`. This means that the C style cast is equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast`.

While you are guaranteed that if you cast the results of this `reinterpret_cast` back to its original type it would yield the same pointer value, you don't have any guarantees about the value of the intermediate pointer, the result is unspecified. This means that `(DerivedA*)&bb` may not point at a valid object at all and the result of converting this pointer to `Base*` (by assigning it to `cc`) may not point at a valid `Base` class.

Because you have no guarantees about the value of `cc`, calling a member function through it may cause *undefined behavior*.